# Checking the existence of an entry in the immediate future date and counting in future date

Tags: mysql

Hope you are doing well!...I am trying to build a mysqlquery for getting the number of entries (combination of sno and mmodel) that are not present in the current date of reference in comparison to the immediate previous date of reference...This will help understand the number of entries that have gone off the list in the current date of reference in comparison to the previous date of reference... Please find the sample data below:

**Input**

```
sno mmodel snapshot_date
r123 S1234 3/1/2022
r3421 S1234 3/1/2022
y123 D2123 3/1/2022
g21q D2123 3/1/2022
W321 G345 3/1/2022
E231 G345 3/1/2022
r123 S1234 3/2/2022    
D891 S1234 3/2/2022    
y123 D2123 3/2/2022
W321 G345 3/2/2022    
K1231 J1231 3/2/2022    
r123 S1234 3/3/2022
D891 S1234 3/3/2022    
H213 V231 3/3/2022    
121k N213 3/3/2022

**Ouput**

date off Delay    
3/1/2022 0    
3/2/2022 3    
3/3/2022 3
```

In the above example for date march 2nd 2022 the number of off delays is 3 because the entries (r3421,S1234) , (g21q,D2123) and (E231,G345) are present on March 1st but are not present in the data on March 2nd

Also the entries (y123,D2123), (W321,G345) and (K1231,J1231) are present on march 2nd but not present in the data on March 3rd so the number off delays for March 3rd is 3.

Comment: How do you know what your "base set" is to use?  so 3/1 is 0 because it matches itself.  But lets say 3/2 had more entries, not fewer... how do you account for the "off delay" then?  As it stands this a full outer self join based on your sno, mmodel and t1.date+1 = t2.date then you're just counting when one side or the other is empty

Comment: Hi @xQbert: Yes the first snapshot_date in ascending order is the date of reference where the offline would be zero and in my case its 03/01 here...For 03/02 I arrive at the number of off delays by comparing each and every entry present in 03/01 with each and every entry present in 03/02 and the number of off delays for 03/02 is the number of entries present in 03/01 which are not present in 03/02..

Comment: So if 3/2 had entry zzzz2 zzzz3 on it wouldn't get counted as it is not in the 3/1 entries?  an nevermind 121k N213 3/3/2022 is that use case.

Comment: @xQbert : I will not worry about the entry in 03/02 as I am only worrying about how many entries present in 03/01 that are not present in 03/02 which will give the number of off delays for 03/02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe... Untested:

[Demo not workign yet.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c79e7efe8ad24f78be0dd5f1631290f)

```
SELECT T1.Sno, t1.mmodel,  t1.snapshot_date, count(T1.*)
FROM TableInput T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableInput T2
   on t1.sno = t2.sno
  and t1.mmodel = t2.mmodel
  and AddDate(t1.snapshot_date, INTERVAL 1 Day) = t2.snapshot_date
WHERE T2.sno is null
GROUP BY T1.Sno, t1.mmodel,  t1.snapshot_date
```

- In essence joins day 1 to day 2 for like items.
- Limits the data on day two to only those that didn't have a match.
- then counts the entries

Comment: Note changed full outer to left.

Comment: Ohh interesting... didn't think about the original date 0... in my models...

Comment: yep... has nueances...

Comment: How is this right?!?!  maybe it moved you to an approach but there's no way this is right... as it stands